# Bernoulli random number generator

Tags: numpy, statistics

I cannot understand how Bernoulli Random Number generator used in numpy is calculated and would like some explanation on it. For example:

```
np.random.binomial(size=3, n=1, p= 0.5)

Results:
[1 0 0]
```

n = number of trails

p = probability of occurrence

size = number of experiments

With how do I determine the generated numbers/results of "0" or "1"?

=================================Update==================================

I created a Restricted Boltzmann Machine which always presents the same results despite being "random" on multiple code executions. The randomize is seeded using
`np.random.seed(10)`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

def sigmoid(u):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-u))

def gibbs_vhv(W, hbias, vbias, x):
    f_s = sigmoid(np.dot(x, W) + hbias)
    h_sample = np.random.binomial(size=f_s.shape, n=1, p=f_s)

    f_u = sigmoid(np.dot(h_sample, W.transpose())+vbias)
    v_sample = np.random.binomial(size=f_u.shape, n=1, p=f_u)
    return [f_s, h_sample, f_u, v_sample]

def reconstruction_error(f_u, x):
    cross_entropy = -np.mean(
        np.sum(
            x * np.log(sigmoid(f_u)) + (1 - x) * np.log(1 - sigmoid(f_u)),
            axis=1))
    return cross_entropy


X = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0]])

#Weight to hidden
W = np.array([[-3.85, 10.14, 1.16],
              [6.69, 2.84, -7.73],
              [1.37, 10.76, -3.98],
              [-6.18, -5.89, 8.29]])

hbias = np.array([1.04, -4.48, 2.50]) #<= 3 bias for 3 neuron in hidden
vbias = np.array([-6.33, -1.68, -1.25, 3.45]) #<= 4 bias for 4 neuron in input


k = 2
v_sample = X
for i in range(k):
    [f_s, h_sample, f_u, v_sample] = gibbs_vhv(W, hbias, vbias, v_sample)
    start = v_sample
    if i < 2:
        print('f_s:', f_s)
        print('h_sample:', h_sample)
        print('f_u:', f_u)
        print('v_sample:', v_sample)
    print(v_sample)
    print('iter:', i, ' h:', h_sample, ' x:', v_sample, ' entropy:%.3f'%reconstruction_error(f_u, v_sample))
```

**Results:**

```
[[1 0 0 0]]
f_s: [[ 0.05678618  0.99652957  0.97491304]]
h_sample: [[0 1 1]]
f_u: [[ 0.99310473  0.00139984  0.99604968  0.99712837]]
v_sample: [[1 0 1 1]]
[[1 0 1 1]]
iter: 0  h: [[0 1 1]]  x: [[1 0 1 1]]  entropy:1.637

f_s: [[  4.90301318e-04   9.99973278e-01   9.99654440e-01]]
h_sample: [[0 1 1]]
f_u: [[ 0.99310473  0.00139984  0.99604968  0.99712837]]
v_sample: [[1 0 1 1]]
[[1 0 1 1]]
iter: 1  h: [[0 1 1]]  x: [[1 0 1 1]]  entropy:1.637
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you rephrase/elaborate, please?

Comment: @kazemakase when i use the function `np.random.binomial(size=3, n=1, p= 0.5)` I am given the results `[1 0 0]`. However, I do not understand how did numpy get the results presented and would like an explanation on it.

Comment: Are you asking how the algorithm works that produces the numbers, or how the result is related to the input parameters?

Comment: I am asking on how the algorithm works to produce the numbers.

Comment: With the update this is practically a new question. You should consider asking this as a separate question, unless you want to invalidate existing answers.... Further hint: show *all* the relevant code. The output indicates iteration, but there is no sign of iteration in your code. Seeing the words **seed**, **iter**, and **same result** mentioned in the same context makes an alarm go off in my head :) (re-seeding in the loop?). So please show exactly how you repeatedly call the `binomial` function and where exactly the seeding occurs.

Comment: @kazemakase Sorry for the lack of clarify in my questions. I have updated the relevant codes in the questions. Hopefully you can have another look at it.

Comment: Good news: it's not the seed! :) You set three different probabilities (`p=f_s`) for three draws of random numbers. `f_s` starts at `[0.057, 0.997, 0.975]` and then converges further towards `[0, 1, 1]`. Therefore it is very unlikely to get a sample other than `[0, 1, 1]`. I don't know if it is correct to use `p=f_s` in your application, but it explains the repeated values.

Comment: By converging towards `[0, 1, 1]`, do you mean that Bernoulli Distribution has an extremely high probability to get `[0, 1, 1]`  as the probability is `[0.057, 0.997, 0.975]`? Therefore, making it unlikely to get any other results. 

If so, I attempted to hard set the values to `[0.3, 0.5, 0.7]` but there is still no sign of "random" values as it gives a constant result of `[1, 0, 1]`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bad luck, I guess. If I set `p=[0.3, 0.5, 0.7]` the first two results of `h_sample` are indeed `[1 0 1]`. But I ran a few more iterations and the third result was `[1 1 0]` followed by `[0 0 1]`. It was just a silly coincidence that the random number generator repeated the first result :) Note that it is actually *desirable* that it can produce the same result in a row - if that was forbidden, individual draws would no longer be independent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I am asking on how the algorithm works to produce the numbers. – WhiteSolstice 35 mins ago

#### Non-technical explanation

If you pass `n=1` to the Binomial distribution it is equivalent to the Bernoulli distribution. In this case the function could be thought of simulating coin flips. `size=3` tells it to flip the coin three times and `p=0.5` makes it a fair coin with equal probabilitiy of *head* (1) or *tail* (0).

The result of `[1 0 0]` means the coin came down once with *head* and twice with *tail* facing up. This is random, so running it again would result in a different sequence like `[1 1 0]`, `[0 1 0]`, or maybe even `[1 1 1]`. Although you cannot get the same number of 1s and 0s in three runs, *on average* you would get the same number.

#### Technical explanation

Numpy implements random number generation in C. The source code for the Binomial distribution can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.3/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c#L442). Actually two different algorithms are implemented.

- If `n * p <= 30` it uses [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).
- If `n * p > 30` the BTPE algorithm of (Kachitvichyanukul and Schmeiser 1988) is used. (The publication is [not freely available](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F42372.42381).)

I think both methods, but certainly the inverse transform sampling, depend on a random number generator to produce uniformly distributed random numbers. Numpy internally uses a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) pseudo random number generator. The uniform random numbers are then transformed into the desired distribution.

Comment: Ooh I see, for a moment I thought there was a way to accurately determine/calculate these values. 

I actually created a Restricted Boltzmann Machine and the values that are given from the usage of `np.random.binomial` is always the same. I have updated the question and hope that you could have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

A Binomially distributed random variable has two parameters `n` and `p`, and can be thought of as the distribution of the number of heads obtained when flipping a biased coin `n` times, where the probability of getting a head at each flip is `p`.  (More formally it is a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter `p`).

For instance, if `n=10` and `p=0.5`, one could simulate a draw from `Bin(10, 0.5)` by flipping a fair coin 10 times and summing the number of times that the coin lands heads.

In addition to the `n` and `p` parameters described above, `np.random.binomial` has an additional `size` parameter. If `size=1`, `np.random.binomial` computes a single draw from the Binomial distribution. If `size=k` for some integer `k`, `k` independent draws from the same Binomial distribution will be computed. `size` can also be an array of indices, in which case a whole `np.array` with the given `size` will be filled with independent draws from the Binomial distribution.

Note that the Binomial distribution is a generalisation of the Bernoulli distribution - in the case that `n=1`, `Bin(n,p)` has the same distribution as `Ber(p)`.

For more information about the binomial distribution see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution